# C++ object oriented return value of virtual function in base class

Tags: c++

I am making a class which inherits off another and must return the value of a function in the base class... It is confusing so I will let the code speak for itself...

```
class ParentClass {
public:
    virtual bool getMyVal();
};

bool ParentClass::getMyVal() {
    return true;   // in my program there is a bit more to it
}

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
public:
    bool getMyVal();
};

bool ChildClass::getMyVal() {
    CalculateMassOfSun();

    return parent::getMyVal();    // Please make sure you read below...
}
```

So this is just an example of what I want to do, not the actual code. As you can see, in ChildClass::getMyVal(), is basically needs to do some pre-computation then run the same function in the parent class and return its value. I know that it is a virtual function in the parent, and that I have not gone about invoking the function in the parent the right way - it is how it is done in PHP and the only way I can think of that makes sense to me and hopefully others at the moment.

So how would I go about doing this? At the moment, I have found something along the lines of:

```
bool ChildClass::getMyVal() : /*ParentClass::*/getMyVal() { ... }
```

however it does not return the value here.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To invoke the base definition of `getMyVal` just prefix the call with the base type name

```
return ParentClass::getMyVal();
```

Comment: Thanks Jared. I thought I had already tried that - obviously not because it works :)

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call `ParentClass` version of `getMyVal()` then do this:

```
bool ChildClass::getMyVal() {
    CalculateMassOfSun();

    return ParentClass::getMyVal(); // this will call parent version
}
```

Comment: Thanks taskinoor, I have upped your answer because it is correct, however I have given the tick to Jared as he got there first - however many thanks for your reply.